# How to map points in a unit square to a regular polygon?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, polygons

I have a set of points in a unit square $x = [-1,1]$ and $y = [-1,1]$ and I want to remap them to their equivalent points in a regular polygon ($n  \geq 3$; Triangle and so on).

I've found a really good article on mapping a unit square to a unit circle
http://mathproofs.blogspot.com/2005/07/mapping-square-to-circle.html

But, I couldn't figure out mapping it to a polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you've heard of the [Schwarz-Christoffel mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping)?  It takes the upper half-plane in $\mathbb{C}$ to a polygon.

Comment: It probably is the solution, but it is way beyond my math knowledge to understand it. I wonder if there is a simpler explanation.

Comment: You do need to understand conformal mapping from Complex Analysis.  But I know of no other solution in general.  And it leads to nice integrals for the triangle.

Comment: Also, I tried voting up your answer, but unfortunately I don't have enough points to do that yet. Sorry.

Comment: @rwb: that's OK, try again later when you do.